# MySQL: Search all fields from a specific type field

Tags: php, mysql, search

I have a MySQL users table with multiple fields including interger user type field (admin or normal). I am looking to have a master search which can search given string in all fields but with a where clause of user type (for a specific type)

I am using

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_fname like '%".$data."%' OR user_lname like '%".$data."%' OR user_login like '%".$data."%' OR user_callsign like '%".$data."%' AND user_type='2'";
```

But When I search, it query the whole table neglecting my user_type clause. I am running out of ideas, please suggest me how would I over come this.

Thanks,

Comment: Since the user_type field is of type integer, remove the single quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to organize your `OR` conditions like `(all ORs)` and then apply `AND` filter so it will not neglect `user_type='2'` AND part

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users
 WHERE (user_fname like '%".$data."%' 
 OR user_lname like '%".$data."%'
 OR user_login like '%".$data."%'
 OR user_callsign like '%".$data."%')
 AND user_type='2'";
```

Comment: Perfect! So simple it was. Thanks so much, you saved my time

Answer (score 0):

You need to parenthesize.  Order of operations for Or and And are equal which means it'll go from left to right

Your query should look more like this:

```
SELECT      * 
FROM    users 
WHERE   (user_fname like '%".$data."%' 
OR      user_lname like '%".$data."%' 
OR      user_login like '%".$data."%' 
OR      user_callsign like '%".$data."%')
AND     user_type='2'
```

Also you should be sanitizing your input and/or using prepared queries.  Otherwise you leave yourself open to massive SQL injection attacks

Look into using PDO or MySQLi (if you must).

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE (user_fname like '%".$data."%' OR user_lname like '%".$data."%' OR user_login like '%".$data."%' OR user_callsign like '%".$data."%') AND user_type='2'";
```

Comment: Can you add a little explanation to your answer?  Goes a long way to helping the questioner!